# How to get the ansible output without Double Quotes

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Var file *./iterate_hosts.yml*

```yaml
---
hostlist:
  - host: '2019'
    inventory_name: 'Level 1'
    ip: '2019'
    mac: 'All industries'
  - host: '2020'
    inventory_name: 'Level 2'
    ip: '2020'
    mac: 'All industries'
  - host: '2021'
    inventory_name: 'Level 3'
    ip: '2021'
    mac: 'All industries'
```

*main.yml*

```yaml
---
- name: csv
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
   - name: var
     include_vars: ./iterate_hosts.yml
   - name: includeing role
     with_sequence: 0-10
     include_role:
       name: csv_test
```

Ansible role (csv_test main file) *csv_test/task/main.yml*

```yaml
---
- set_fact:
    count123: '{{item}}'
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostlist[item]}}"
```

Error:

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute '0'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/csv/csv_test/tasks/main.yml

Observations:

- the value in the `{{ hostlist[count123] }}` should be `{{ hostlist[0] }}"` for first iteration and so on.
- but Ansible is taking 0 as the string "0"

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "count123": "0"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

This solution works if the value be like **`"count123": 0`**

How we can escape the quotes and get the integer rather than a string?

Expectation: I have to iterate through the *./iterate_hosts.yml* and for that I am using the `with_sequence: 0-10` in my *main.yml* file.

So:

- for `hostlist[count123]` (which should be `count123=0` for the first iteration), it should print the content form *./iterate_hosts.yml*

  ```yaml
  host: '2019'
  inventory_name: 'Level 1'
  ip: '2019'
  mac: 'All industries'
  ```
- for `hostlist[count123]` (which should be `count123=1` for the second iteration) it should print

  ```yaml
  host: '2020'
  inventory_name: 'Level 2'
  ip: '2020'
  mac: 'All industries'
  ```
- and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`int`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#int) Jinja filter for this.

So your file *csv_test/task/main.yml* ends up being:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    count123: "{{ item | int }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostlist[item | int] }}"
```

*Note that the fact that `with_sequence` is generating strings is raised in the documentation*

> - Generated items are strings. Use Jinja2 filters to convert items to preferred type, e.g. `{{ 1 + item|int }}`

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/sequence_lookup.html#synopsis*</sup>

---

Here is a full working playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostlist[item | int] }}" 
      with_sequence: 0-2
      vars:
        hostlist:
          - host: '2019'
            inventory_name: 'Level 1'
            ip: '2019'
            mac: 'All industries'
          - host: '2020'
            inventory_name: 'Level 2'
            ip: '2020'
            mac: 'All industries'
          - host: '2021'
            inventory_name: 'Level 3'
            ip: '2021'
            mac: 'All industries'
```

That gives the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => {
    "msg": {
        "host": "2019",
        "inventory_name": "Level 1",
        "ip": "2019",
        "mac": "All industries"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": {
        "host": "2020",
        "inventory_name": "Level 2",
        "ip": "2020",
        "mac": "All industries"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": {
        "host": "2021",
        "inventory_name": "Level 3",
        "ip": "2021",
        "mac": "All industries"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Very close but you were first ;) Deleting my answer.

Comment: made the changes:

- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostipmacs[count123 | int]}}"
 

i dnt know why the iteration is always taking the first list set

output
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "count123": "0"
    },
    "changed": false
}

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "host": "2019",
        "inventory_name": "Level 1",
        "ip": "99999",
        "mac": "All industries"
    }
}

Comment: I would have made `count123: "{{ item | int }}"` but that's really a matter of point of view...

Comment: the expectation is  for "count123":"0" it should print the first set of values from ./iterate_hosts.yml and similarly for "count":"1" it should print second set of values form ./iterate_hosts.yml and so on

Comment: @Vaibhav tbh it is not fully clear what you expect, you should maybe edit this in your question. Is the `set_fact` there for debugging only? Is the `debug` there for debugging only?

Comment: But anyway the concept stays the same `var_that_holds_the_string_representation_of_an_int | int` will give you the said int.

Comment: And if you are telling us that you are always getting the first element, this could be a reason why (from the linked Jinja doc): *If the conversion doesn’t work it will return 0*

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for the solution..  you were right ... it was my bad I didn't notice that in the actual yml the values are repeated, that's why I got the repeated value.. ..   Now it's sorted out ......Cheers :)  happy learning